# Boolean Algebra: How does $\bar A\bar BC+\bar A\bar C\bar D+A\bar CD+\bar AB\bar C$ become $\bar A\bar BC + \bar A\bar C\bar D+A\bar CD+B\bar CD$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

I'm trying to understand one of the steps taken during the process of getting a cnf in Boolean algebra but I just cant understand what is happening here.

$$\bar A \bar B C + \bar A \bar C \bar D +  A \bar C  D + \bar A  B  \bar C$$
$$\bar A \bar B C + \bar A \bar C \bar D +  A \bar C  D + B  \bar C D$$

It seems like they just exchange the !A for D , but I cannot understand which of the Boolean algebra laws they used.

Could someone help me understand it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is why:

$$A'B'C+A'C'D'+AC'D+A'BC'\overset{Absorption}{=}$$

$$A'B'C+A'C'D'+(AC'D+ABC'D)+(A'BC'D+A'BC'D')\overset{Association, Commutation}{=}$$

$$A'B'C+(A'C'D'+A'BC'D')+AC'D+(ABC'D+A'BC'D)\overset{Absorption, Adjacency}{=}$$

$$A'B'C+A'C'D'+AC'D+BC'D$$

Answer (score 1):

Another trick:

The [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem) says:

$XY+X'Z=XY+X'Z+YZ$

which can be generalized to:

**Nested Consensus**

$WXY+WX'Z=WXY+WX'Z+WYZ$

Applying this to your statement:

$$A'B'C+A'C'D'+AC'D+A'BC'$$

$$\overset{Consensus: AC'D+A'BC' = AC'D+A'BC'+BC'D}{=}$$

$$A'B'C+A'C'D'+AC'D+A'BC'+BC'D$$

$$\overset{Consensus: A'C'D'+BC'D = A'C'D'+BC'D+A'BC'}{=}$$

$$A'B'C+A'C'D'+AC'D+BC'D$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\bar{A}B\bar{C} = \bar{A}B\bar{C}D + \bar{A}B\bar{C}\bar{D}
$$

the second piece $\bar{A}B\bar{C}\bar{D}$ is already a subset of $\bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D}$ so you get

$$
\begin{align}
\bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + \bar{A}{B}\bar{C} &= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + (\bar{A}B\bar{C}D + \bar{A}B\bar{C}\bar{D}) \\
&= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + (\bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + \bar{A}B\bar{C}\bar{D}) + {A}\bar{C}{D} + \bar{A}B\bar{C}D \\
&= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + \bar{A}B\bar{C}D
\end{align}
$$

Now, ${A}B\bar{C}D$ is a subset of ${A}\bar{C}D$ so you can split it out:

$$
\begin{align}
\bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + \bar{A}{B}\bar{C} &= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + (\bar{A}B\bar{C}D + \bar{A}B\bar{C}\bar{D}) \\
&= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + (\bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + \bar{A}B\bar{C}\bar{D}) + {A}\bar{C}{D} + \bar{A}B\bar{C}D \\
&= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + \bar{A}B\bar{C}D \\
&= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + ({A}\bar{C}{D} + {A}B\bar{C}D) + \bar{A}B\bar{C}D \\
&= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + ({A}B\bar{C}D + \bar{A}B\bar{C}D) \\
&= \bar{A}\bar{B}{C} + \bar{A}\bar{C}\bar{D} + {A}\bar{C}{D} + B\bar{C}D
\end{align}
$$